# Passing custom log4j.properties file from s3

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I'm trying to set custom logging configurations. If I add the log file to the cluster and reference it in my spark submit, the configurations take effect. But if I try to access the file using `--files s3://...` then it doesn't work.

Works (assuming I placed the file in the home dir):

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties \
```

Doesn't work:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--files s3://my_path/log4j.properties \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties \
```

How can I use a config file in s3 to set the logging configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly Log4J loads its files from the local filesystem, always.

You can use configs inside a JAR, and as spark will download JARs with your job, you should be able to get it indirectly. Create a JAR containing only the log4j.properties file, tell spark to load it with the job

Comment: Do you have an example or documentation? I'm not sure how to point to files from the jar

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--jars https://link-to-my-jar.jar \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=? \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=? \
--class com.blah.Main https://link-to-my-jar.jar \
```

Comment: oh, no need  set any log4j options.. Just create a JAR with nothing but the log4J.properties file. Log4J looks for a resource /log4.properties as soon as it loads. (Note: if you have >1 log4 resource life gets complicated, and that spark conf one may get picked up first...)